# Can't append 2 strings the way I want

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am have some issues with something I thought it should be pretty straightforward in python. So I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
a = ["n","alpha"]
a = np.array(a)
print(a[0])
print(a[1])
a[0] = a[0]+"+"+a[1]
print(a[0])
```

The output of this is:

```
'n'
'alpha'
'n+alp'
```

Why is that last output like that instead of `'n+alpha'` and how can I make it the way I want? Thank you!

Comment: I think you are doing it in wrong way, try a[0]+a[1]

Comment: This is because how strings work in numpy. Try line 3: `a = np.array(a, dtype=object)`

Comment: @Deadpool I want my final output for the first element to be "n+alpha"

Comment: Pay attention to the `a.dtype`.  A string dtype array has a fixed length.  It's not exactly the same the Python string type.